# AVAudioPlayer error

Tags: objective-c

i'm using this code but it's not working;

**Import:**

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>
```

**Header File:**

```
AVAudioPlayer *_audioPlayer;
```

**Code:**

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/welcome.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

    NSError *error;
    _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    _audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;

if (_audioPlayer == nil)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
}
else
{
     [_audioPlayer play];   

    NSLog(@"PLAY");

}
```

**The NSLog:**

```
Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-43 "The operation couldn‚Äôt be completed. (OSStatus error -43.)"
```

it's not working on my iPhone (5.1) iPad (5.0) iPhone 5.0 Simulator.

Anyone know how i can fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get that error if no file was found at the path you specified.

Also, check that you do have a file **welcome.mp3** and that it is bundled with the application target. To do that, select the target, go to **Build Phases** tab and make sure the file is in the list **Copy Bundle Resources**. If it is not there, add it.